# C++ get hour and minutes from string

Tags: c++, scanf

I'm writing C++ code for school in which I can only use the std library, so no boost. I need to parse a string like "14:30" and parse it into:

```
unsigned char hour;
unsigned char min;
```

We get the string as a c++ string, so no direct pointer. I tried all variations on this code:

```
sscanf(hour.c_str(), "%hhd[:]%hhd", &hours, &mins);
```

but I keep getting wrong data. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: No only the minsare correct when I use %d:%d. When I use %d[:]%d the hours are correct.

Comment: `sscanf` is not c++ you know

Comment: @izomorphius, the `sscanf` is C++ because it is defined in the header `<cstdio>` and available in the language.  Perhaps you are referrring to IO streams, which is not in C language.

Comment: You are getting rubbish because `%d` denotes an integer for `sscanf`, and you pass `usigned char` as an output argument.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I know that you **can** use `sscanf` in c++ I am just pointing out this is not the c++ way to solve the problem.

Comment: @izomorphius, why is it not the C++ way?  I'll agree that it is not a safe function, but it is more efficient that using streams and all those manipulators, just for 2 numbers.

Comment: @izomorphius Not really sure what "the c++ way" means unless it is code for "this won't compile in C" and nothing more. But `sscanf` is just a much, and just as *valid*, C++ as it is C. Both standards declare it. The C-standard *defines* it in 7.21.6.7; the C++ standard supports it in 27.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone else has mentioned, you have to use `%d` format specified (or `%u`). As for the alternative approaches, I am not a big fan of the "because C++ has feature XX it must be used" and oftentimes resort to C-level functions. Though I never use `scanf()`-like stuff as it got its own problems. That  being said, here is how I would parse your string using `strtol()` with error checking:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    unsigned char hour;
    unsigned char min;

    const char data[] = "12:30";
    char *ep;

    hour = (unsigned char)strtol(data, &ep, 10);
    if (!ep || *ep != ':') {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot parse hour: '%s' - wrong format\n", data);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    min = (unsigned char)strtol(ep+1, &ep, 10);
    if (!ep || *ep != '\0') {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot parse minutes: '%s' - wrong format\n", data);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Hours: %u, Minutes: %u\n", hour, min);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good solution.  For something this simple, manual checking and using `strtol` would seem to be the best solution.  I wouldn't just cast the results of `strtol` to `unsigned char`, however.  I'd assign it to a `long`, and check the range, before converting to anything else.  And you don't need the obfuscating `!ep` in your `if`s: the standard guarantees that `ep` will not be `NULL` after calling `strtol`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I absolutely agree with you on this one my friend.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it realy helped me understand more of C++. @James Kanze: thank you for your comments on every post they really add value.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, of course, that you are using `sscanf`.  And that
you're using some very special type for the hours and minutes, instead
of `int`.  Since you're parsing a string of exactly 5 characters, the
simplest solution is just to ensure that all of the characters are legal
in that position, using `isdigit` for characters 0, 1, 3 and 4, and
comparing to `':'` for character 2.  Once you've done that, it's trivial
to create an `std::istringstream` from the string, and input into an
`int`, a `char` (which you'll ignore afterwards) and a second `int`.  If
you want to be more flexible in the input, for example allowing things
like `"9:45"` as well, you can skip the initial checks, and just input 
into `int`, `char` and `int`, then check that the `char` contains `':'`
(and that the two `int` are in range).

As to why your `sscanf` is failing: you're asking it to match something
like `"12[:]34"`, which is *not* what you're giving it.  I'm not sure
whether you're trying to use `"%hhd:%hhd"`, or if for some reason you
really do want a character class, in which case, you have to use `[` as
a conversion specifier, and then ignore the input: `"%hhd%*[:]%hhd"`.
(This would allow accepting more than one character as the separator,
but otherwise, I don't see the advantage.  Also, technically at least,
using `%d` and then passing the address of an `unsigned` integral types
is not supported, `%hhd` *must* be a `signed char`.  In practice,
however, I don't think you'll ever run into any problems for
non-negative input values less than 128.)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by izomorphius `sscanf` and variants are not C++ they are C. The C++ way would be to use streams. The following works (it's not amazingly flexible but should give you an idea)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string str = "14:30";

    stringstream sstrm;

    int hour,min;

    sstrm << str;

    sstrm >> hour;
    sstrm.get(); // get colon
    sstrm >> min;

    cout << hour << endl;
    cout << min << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You could also use [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) to get everything upto the colon.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

```
unsigned tmp_hour, tmp_mins;
unsigned char hour, mins;

sscanf(hour.c_str(), "%u:%u", &tmp_hours, &tmp_mins);
hour = tmp_hours;
mins = tmp_mins;
```

Less messing around with obscure `scanf` options. I would add some error checking too.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `h` in `%hhd` is not a valid format specifier.  The correct specifier for decimal integers is `%d`.

As R.Martinho Fernandes says in his comment, `%d:%d` will match two numbers separated by a colon (':').

Did you want something different?

You can always read the entire text string and parse it any way you want.

Comment: The `h` are length modifiers.  `"%hhd"` assigns to a `signed char`, rather than to an `int`.  Since his pointers are to `unsigned char`, `"%d:%d"` will cause a core dump on most machines (because one of the `int` will be misaligned), and overwrite other memory on an Intel.

Comment: @JamesKanze:  What version of C or C++ mentions `hhd` specifier?  My Special Edition of Bjarne's book only mentions one `h`: "an optional character h, specifying that a following d, o, x or u corresponds to a short integer argument."  The Harbison & Steel 2nd edition, doesn't mention `h` as a `scanf` format specifier. Thanks.

Comment: The C standard.  It's not an `hhd` specifier.  It's a `d` specifier preceded by an `hh` length modifier.  It may be C99.  It surprised me too when I looked it up; I don't remember it from back when I still used C.

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf` with `%hhd:%hhd` seems to work perfectly fine:

```
std::string time("14:30");
unsigned char hour, min;
sscanf(time.c_str(), "%hhd:%hhd", &hour, &min);
```

Note that the `hh` length modifier is simply to allow storing the value in an unsigned char.

However, `sscanf` is from the C Standard Library and there are better C++ ways to do this. A C++11 way to do this is using `stoi`:

```
std::string time("14:30");
unsigned char hour = std::stoi(time);
unsigned char min = std::stoi(time.substr(3));
```

In C++03, we can use `stringstream` instead but it's a bit of a pain if you really want it in a `char`:

```
std::stringstream stream("14:30");
unsigned int hour, min;
stream >> hour;
stream.ignore();
stream >> min;
```

Comment: Technically, at least according to the Posix standard (which claims conformity with the C standard here), the `"hh"` modifier has no impact on the signedness, and `"%d"` requires a signed integral type, so `"%hhd"` requires a `signed char`, and not an `unsigned char`.